# При наведении на li, менялся цвет в before

Tags: html, css

Собственно, нужно чтобы менялся цвет символа в li:before при наведении на саму li.
Делаю так, но не работает

```
.slidernav .nav ul li:hover .slidernav .nav ul li:before {
    color: #fff;
} 
.slidernav .nav ul li:before {
    content: "\f061"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  color: #61acfe;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Можно html-разметку?

Answer (score 2):

К решению сам пришел,

```
.slidernav .nav ul li:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
}
```